# How to add trailing spaces to format specifier in String resource file, in Android?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, formatting

I have a list view with a list of country codes and country names like below:

```
+351 (PT) Portugal
+1684 (AS) American Samoa
```

And I'm using this String resource:

```
<string name="country_code_picker_item" translatable="false">+%1$d (%2$s) %3$s</string>
```

What I want to do is align the country initials, by adding extra spaces in case of the country code having less then 4 numbers. I know that to add leading 0's it is like this %1$04d, but I want trailing spaces, like this:

```
+351  (PT) Portugal
+1684 (AS) American Samoa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-`:

```xml
<string name="country_code_picker_item" translatable="false">+%1$-4d (%2$s) %3$s</string>
```

Spaces will be added at the end of the converted value as required to fill the minimum width of the field.

For further information, you can see [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)'s sections: Details -> General.